# Magento:2.3.1 How to remove loader from checkout when changing payment method

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.1, autoloader

How to remove the Loading functionality (loader) from the checkout steps when we change the payment method from one to another in the existed methods?

Comment: have you got any error in inspect element ?

Comment: so you need to remove the only image?

Comment: yes loader when payment method change